# Visual Studio 2015 Designer Crashes in all Win10 UAP projects ("The app didn't start.")

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, uwp, blend, visual-studio-designer

The xaml visual designer crashes for all WIN10 UWP projects, including ones created from the standard template with no code added. I don't know when it started because I thought it was a problem with my project until I tried creating some new ones.  The error is given below and in the screen shot at the bottom.

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
The app didn't start. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8027025B)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.AppPackage.AppPackageNativeMethods.IApplicationActivationManager.ActivateApplication(String appUserModelId, String activationContext, ActivateOptions options, Int32& processId)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.AppPackage.DesignerWrtUtility.ActivateApplication(String appUserModelId, String activationContext, Object site, Boolean isRunningElevated)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.ActivateApplicationInternal(String appUserModelId, String activationContext, Object site)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateDesignerProcess(String applicationPath, String clientPort, Uri hostUri, IDictionary environmentVariables, Int32& processId, Object& processData)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.ProcessIsolationDomain..ctor(ProcessDomainFactory factory, IIsolationBoundary boundary, AppDomainSetup appDomainInfo, IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, String baseDirectory)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary boundary)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary boundary)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.CreateInstance[T](Type type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedObjectFactory.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerHost.Services.VSIsolationService.CreateObjectFactory(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, IObjectCatalog catalog)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, CancellationToken cancelToken, DesignerServiceEntry& entry, IServiceProvider serviceOverrides)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.InvokeWithCulture[T](CultureInfo culture, Func`2 func, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.<>c__DisplayClass10_0`1.<StartTask>b__0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

I have tried  the following:

- Running as administrator
- Disabling Project Code
- Clearing the \Designer\ShadowCache folder
- Adding read permissions to the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT for All Application Packagesas well as C:\Windows.
- Running the visual studio repair.
- I am not using TrueCrypt (people with similar issues were)
- I have tried changing the platform target to ARM, x64 and x86 (rebuilding and reloading after each)

None of these have fixed the issue. I get the same error in blend. Any ideas?

[image: Error Message Screenshot]

Comment: Have you installed the latest Windows 10 SDK?

Comment: @Harvey I am trying to do that now, the UPDATE button with UAC shield is disabled though, and there is no message explaining why. Know anything off the top of your head?

Comment: Best off to download it from Microsoft and install https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk

Comment: @Harvey When I try that I get "You must uninstall the Windows Software Development Kit - Windows 10.0.10586.15 before you can install the latest version of the kit. Visual Studio was trying to install 10.0.10240 is that also what the link you sent me is? Will uninstalling the "newer" sdk cause any problems do you think?

**Edit**: Nevermind, uninstalled and reinstalling the SDK now.

Comment: That is very odd! i just grabbed that link from Microsoft so that would be the latest. I would recommend uninstalling your SDK  and re-installing from Microsoft directly.  (Even if it is older) as it may sort out your issues. I have had 100's of problems with this terrible platform!

Comment: @Harvey Reinstalling the Windows 10 SDK fixed my problem, want to post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A reinstall of the latest Windows 10 SDK should fix this problem. This can be gathered from Microsoft I've had many issues like this in the past. Certain versions tend to be buggy.

Comment: What a pain!! 2015 worked a charm for god knows how long and all of a sudden, it started acting up generating the above error! This seems to be as a result from installing various updates as per vs notification i.e. Azure, ASP.NET MVC 5 RC1, Apache Cordova, Application insight - but none of these appear to be related to the xaml designer, so the only one left was .NET 2015 enterprise patch. While I can't say for sure which one it is, I assume it's that one. I installed them all on the 14/02/2016 but re-install the SDK did the trick! Thanks.

Comment: By the way, this didn't last! Less than a day later after re-installing it, it happened again and has been happening since! So frustrating!!

Comment: It happens from time to time, I have no idea what causes it, my guess it has something to do with Windows update. Either way it's a terrible buggy system